# Physician's scale with sliding weights

Tags: terminologie, santé-et-médecine

To me, a doctor's scale has eye-level weights that can be adjusted for maximum accuracy. Do such scales exist in France? What are they called?

Comment: I went ahead and edited your question to remove the part about where one can buy such a scale since that bit is off-topic. Otherwise your question is good to go :)

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron Done. Mais bon, j'ai toujours du mal à faire des réponses évidentes et qui ne demande aucun effort de recherche, je ne vois pas trop en quoi ça peut bénéficier à la réputation du site.

Comment: Really!!! Thanks for being so open-minded.

Answer (score 1):

If [that](http://demandware.edgesuite.net/aamb_prd/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-master-catalog/default/dw521bfe46/images/highres/400KL-099-1.jpg)'s you call a doctor's scale I haven't seen any of those in France for ages. I've had a look around and they can still be bought, they're called *Pèse-personne à colonne mécanique*. *Pèse-personne* being the word for "scales", *à colonne* for the vertical rod and *mécanique* as "mechanical".

Comment: The OP is asking for a *pèse-personne*, but for completeness I think it is important to note that the general translation for *scales* is *balance*. When scales are used for measuring the weight of a human, one mostly uses *pèse-personne* instead.

Comment: @Law29 OP was asking for a specific object (not about scales in general, a word he most certainly knew)  with the intend to buy one ("and where can one buy them") so I gave him the commercial name so that he could find one easily...

Answer (score 1):

They are called *pèse-personne à colonne* as indicated by Laure.

The *colonne* signifies that there's a vertical rod or column, at the end of which the weight measurement can be read. Some "pèse-personne à colonne" are mechanical, some are electronic (based on how the weight is displayed).

The mechanism with the counterweights that slide on a horizontal bar is called "contrepoids coulissants" (sliding counterweights). There are other ways of mechanically indicating a weight, e.g. with a round display.

The full description of what you're looking for is a "pèse-personne mécanique à colonne à contrepoids coulissants".